# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field()

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have issue like here below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field()
  in /Users/My Repo/project_prod/wp-content/themes/project/functions.php:388
Stack trace:
 #0 /Users/My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): {closure}('')
 #1 /Users/My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
 #2 /Users/My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
 #3 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2012): do_action('wp_print_script...')
 #4 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): print_head_scripts('')
 #5 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
 #6 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
 #7 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-admin/admin-header.php(146): do_action('admin_print_scr...')
 #8 /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-admin/index.php(137): require_once('/Users//My ...')
 #9 {main} thrown in /Users//My Repo/project_prod/wp-content/themes/project/functions.php on line 388
```

Unfortunately, this issue is blocking access to the admin panel, as well as homepage.
I did changed theme via database to update conflicting plugin (probably ACF), unfortunately it is not possible - the plugins list is empty.

Lines throwing error in functions.php looks like below:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', function () {
  global $post;
  $sections =  get_field('sekcje',$post);
  $dequeue = true;
  if (!empty($sections)) {
      foreach ($sections as $section) {
        if ($section["acf_fc_layout"] == 'kontakt') {
        $dequeue = false;
      }
    }
  }
  wp_dequeue_script( 'google-recaptcha' );
  wp_dequeue_script( 'wpcf7-recaptcha' );
});
```

Does anyone has an idea

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is executed before you have loaded the ACF plugin. It would be best if all your code goes in the `plugins_loaded` hook.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function () {
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', function () {
      global $post;
      $sections =  get_field('sekcje',$post);
      $dequeue = true;
      if (!empty($sections)) {
          foreach ($sections as $section) {
            if ($section["acf_fc_layout"] == 'kontakt') {
            $dequeue = false;
          }
        }
      }
      wp_dequeue_script( 'google-recaptcha' );
      wp_dequeue_script( 'wpcf7-recaptcha' );
    });
});
```

Maybe even reactivating ACF can fix the problem.

Generally, you need to force ACF to load before your plugin to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it works as when I have commented out this code, so I have an access to the admin panel, but without any plugins. There was installed Google Authenticator installed, could it be the issue? Is the any way to turn it off without access to plugin management?

Comment: It's hard to say without first looking at the code and doing some careful debugging. I gave an answer about how ACF functions work in other plugins, but it's up to you to go line by line and investigate.